# Setting maxlength for each row in a multiline texbox

Tags: max, rows, multiline

I want to set maxlength to 5 characters for each row in a mulitiline textbox.

Comment: HTML? Winforms? iPhone? What exactly are you talking about?

Comment: I don't know how it can be done, but this would be a job for JavaScript!

Comment: ...then so do I! What are we doing this in?

Answer (score 0):

if you are talking with respect to asp.net textbox control then it can be done by setting the columns property to 5